# adding days to a date in R

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
   date rmean
1/2/2004    6
1/5/2004    30
1/6/2004    27
1/7/2004    20
1/8/2004    10
1/9/2004    22
1/12/2004   21
1/13/2004   18
1/14/2004   19
1/15/2004   7
1/16/2004   9
1/19/2004   11
1/20/2004   18
1/21/2004   26
1/26/2004   8
1/27/2004   16
1/28/2004   19
1/29/2004   4
1/30/2004   1
2/3/2004    11
2/4/2004    9
2/5/2004    26
2/6/2004    16
2/9/2004    25
2/10/2004   2
2/11/2004   6
2/12/2004   2
2/13/2004   25
2/16/2004   17
2/17/2004   21
2/18/2004   26
2/19/2004   6
2/20/2004   14
2/23/2004   4
2/24/2004   7
2/25/2004   19
2/26/2004   10
2/27/2004   23
```

I want to find the rmean of  (20 days + 15th of each month).

Note: if there isn't a value for rmean of that date in my data (some days are skipped), i want it to find the rmean of closest day of the

something like this but ( 20 + 15th of each month) instead of 15 :

```
dt <- Dataframe[, list(day15=abs(mday(date)-15) == min(abs(mday(date)-15)), 
                       date, rmean), by=list(year(date), month(date))]
dt[day15==TRUE]
Finale = dt[day15==TRUE , .SD[1,] ,by=list(month, year)]
```

The expected output for my example above:

```
date        rmean
 2/4/2004    9
```

Comment: Try to avoid including irrelevant information in your questions... the fact that it's a 'loading day' or 'arriving day' doesn't really matter for the problem, and just complicates the question. Do you simply want to find the values, from the `rmean` column, that correspond to the dates 20 days after the 15th of each month (or the closest days to those dates)?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i want, i'll edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: What behaviour do you expect when there are multiple closest dates? (e.g. the day before and the day after a given date)

Comment: @ZKC In addition to jbaums comments , what is the expected output here ? Also you should include used packages (`data.table` here).

Comment: If there is multiple closest dates, i want to get the one with the biggest rmean. Thanks

Comment: @agstudy the expected output should be a list with the dates (20 days + 15th of each month) or closest date and the rmean that correspond to it

Comment: @ZKC You have already wrote this I think. I mean the expected output on the given data sample. You should add it to your answer not to the comment below.

Comment: @agstudy i added the expected output to my question, thanks.

Comment: @akrun Yes, it should be one row for my example. Your answer didn't work it still gives me the rmean of the 15th day not (20 + 15th). Thanks

Comment: @ZKC Yes, Sorry, I noticed it after I commented.  I added +20 to the numeric index and not the `date`

Comment: `DT[, .SD[which.min(abs(date[abs(mday(date)-15)==min(abs(mday(date)-15))]+20-date))]]#date rmean
1: 2004-02-04     9`

Comment: @akrun You should know that is not good to give answers in the comments. A hint yes but not the entire answer.

Comment: @agstudy Thanks, yes, I do understand that.  The OP provided only one month of data and I didn't tested by creating one.  So, it may or may not work in the original dataset.

Comment: @ZKC Have you tried the one I suggested? (though, it was not tested only with the data you provided)

Comment: @akrun Yes but i keep getting this error : Warning message:
In unclass(time1) - unclass(time2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Not sure we can work this out easily without having your data at hand. Are you still having problems?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it with `base` R.

First, some dummy data:

```
d <- data.frame(date=as.Date('1/1/2004', '%d/%m/%Y') + sort(sample(364, 200)),
                x=runif(200))

head(d)

#         date          x
# 1 2004-01-02 0.29818227
# 2 2004-01-03 0.12543617
# 3 2004-01-04 0.78145310
# 4 2004-01-05 0.30456904
# 5 2004-01-06 0.45228066
# 6 2004-01-07 0.07511554
```

Calculate arrival dates within the date range of the data:

```
arrival <- 
  seq(as.Date(sprintf('15/%s', format(min(d$date), '%m/%Y')), '%d/%m/%Y'), 
      as.Date(sprintf('15/%s', format(max(d$date), '%m/%Y')), '%d/%m/%Y'),
      by='month') + 20

arrival

#  [1] "2004-02-04" "2004-03-06" "2004-04-04" "2004-05-05" "2004-06-04" "2004-07-05"
#  [7] "2004-08-04" "2004-09-04" "2004-10-05" "2004-11-04" "2004-12-05" "2005-01-04"
```

Find the closest date to each of the arrival dates (taking that with max `x` value if there are two closest dates), and return a `data.frame` with the "arrival" dates, the closest dates to each of these arrival dates, and the corresponding values of `x`.

```
cbind(arrival, do.call(rbind, lapply(arrival, function(x) {
  closest <- which(abs(d$date - x) == min(abs(d$date - x)))
  d[closest[which.max(d$x[closest])], ]
})))

#        arrival       date          x
# 25  2004-02-04 2004-02-03 0.78836413
# 45  2004-03-06 2004-03-06 0.61214949
# 63  2004-04-04 2004-04-04 0.49171847
# 79  2004-05-05 2004-05-05 0.02989788
# 93  2004-06-04 2004-06-04 0.25923715
# 109 2004-07-05 2004-07-05 0.90330331
# 120 2004-08-04 2004-08-04 0.48133237
# 139 2004-09-04 2004-09-03 0.12280267
# 151 2004-10-05 2004-10-03 0.46888891
# 169 2004-11-04 2004-11-04 0.40397949
# 186 2004-12-05 2004-12-04 0.18685615
# 200 2005-01-04 2004-12-30 0.97462347
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks alot for that but i keep getting this error: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 126, 0

Comment: @ZKC: You mean when you apply it to _your_ data? What is `length(arrival)`? Make sure you run the block of code that assigns to `arrival`, and make sure you change `d$date` in both blocks of code as necessary.

Comment: i changed d$date, and i am getting this error now : Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 126, 125

Comment: length of arrival is 126

Comment: @ZKC: Is there anything strange about `lapply(arrival, function(x) { closest <- which(abs(d$date - x) == min(abs(d$date - x))); d[closest[which.max(d$x[closest])], ] })`? Any `NULL` or `NA`? What's it's length?

Comment: I think i know where the problem is, in the last month of the data, the code apply ( 20 + 15th of the month ) but there isn't a next month to find the value of x of that date. I hope this is clear. Can we solve this? Thanks alot @jbaums

Comment: @ZKC: That shouldn't matter... it just means the closest date might be quite distant. See the last row of my example output. The arrival date is 4/1/2005, and the closest date is 30/12/2004.

Comment: Oh :( , nothing strange about the code but i am getting also : Warning message:
In data.table::data.table(...) :
  Item 2 is of size 125 but maximum size is 126 (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items)